# GitHub Actions conditional execution always shows change because comparing to main instead of private branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub action that does a conditional execution of a job where it builds and runs the tests for a project only if there was a change in one specific directory of the code. Seems like a common thing to do. I used this as a reference: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/paths-changes-filter

**Problem**  it always shows it as "changed" because it is comparing if my branch is different from main which it is. I want it to determine if there were any files changed in this specific directory ('libs/storage/Tsavorite/**') and if so, then it will run all the steps to build and test it.

Also - I don't want to set it in the "paths" part at the top because I will have a job that runs every time in this same CI. So, I have the core part running every time and the libs\storage\tsavorite part only run if that is changed.

Looking at the output, the step where it is checking for change, it says:
"Change detection refs/remotes/origin/main..refs/remotes/origin/darrenge/TsavIntoCI" so that tells me it is comparing main to my branch.

**CI yml file:**

```
name: My CI
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    paths-ignore:
      - 'website/**'
      - '*.md'
    branches:
      - darrenge/TsavIntoCI
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE: 1
  DOTNET_NOLOGO: true

jobs:
  changes:      
    runs-on: windows-latest  
    outputs:            
      tsavorite: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.tsavorite }}
    steps:  
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Check if Tsavorite changed
      uses: dorny/paths-filter@v3
      id: filter
      with:
        filters: |
          tsavorite:
            - 'libs/storage/Tsavorite/**'  

  verify-changes:      
    needs: changes
    runs-on: windows-latest  
    if: needs.changes.outputs.tsavorite == 'true' 
    steps:
      - name: CHANGES MADE
        run: echo "CHANGES were made"


  verify-NO-changes:      
    needs: changes
    runs-on: windows-latest  
    if: needs.changes.outputs.tsavorite == 'false'
    steps:
      - name: NO CHANGES MADE
        run: echo "NO CHANGES were made"
```

I am expecting it to only run the "changes were made" part of the code if a file in the commit that forced this run was made in libs/storage/Tsavorite/**

Comment: Try adding `with:base: ${{ github.ref }}` to the paths-filter step. That will compare the changes only in the most recent commit on the same branch. If I understand you right, that's what you're trying to do: evaluate the changes in the _commit_ as opposed to the entire ref against your default branch. See [examples](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter?tab=readme-ov-file#examples) for "**Detect changes against the most recent commit on the same branch before the push**"